# Rename {color-profile} to {color-profiles} (or delete it?)

Tags: discussion, tagging

... because we prefer plural tags. ([color-profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-profile) ⇒ [color-profiles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-profiles)).

Maybe this tag isn't even necessary at all, as we have [color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color); in this case it could be deleted. However, I don't know enough about this area to judge that.

Comment: I would delete that tag, since nobody uses it. For, simple [search for "CMYK"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=CMYK) gives 93 results, only two of which are tagged with this tag.

Comment: Agreed. There are only [three questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-profile) that use the tag at all; I wouldn't even call that a niche.